# How to read a cron expression from property file? for Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler

```
@Profile(value={"Local"})
@QuartzJob(name="Job", cronExp="0 00 9 * * ?")
```

Can we read cronExp from properties file? Please suggest

Comment: here the need is with separating Quartz job and scheduled

Comment: I need help in separating the cronExp from @QuartzJob